# Can I use a funtion AWS `put_object()` API an option binary or ascii mode like a function PHP `ftp_put()`?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, ftp

PHP have a frunction ftp_put().
And also We can use mode binary mode or ascii mode too.

Now I have a job for changing a storage from `php-FTP` to `AWS-S3`.

Does `put_object()` has an option saving binary or ascii mode?
or is there good hint to solve this problem?

Have a nice day.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're facing? As far as I know, there are not such options for S3 (since S3 transfer files over HTTP(S)).

Comment: Also you know, `ftp_put()` provide two options binary and ascii modes.

I want to be sure of Does S3 has an option choosing mode(binary and ascii).

And thanks your attention!

Comment: I'm aware of that, but as I mentioned, S3 doesn't use FTP to transfer files and you don't need to set the mode. You also didn't answer the question. What is the _actual problem_ you're facing? Are you having some specific issue when uploading to S3 using `put_object()`?